# Cochains as a set of simplexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

I know that if  $X$ is a simplicial complex then $C_{n}$ is the free abelian group on the n-dim simplices (ex. $C_{0}$ is the free abelian group on vertices etc).  Then, the elements of $C_{n}$ are called n-dim chains. Now, in order to get the cochains we replace the groups $C_{n}$ by $C^{*}_{n}=Hom(C_{n}, G)$, where $G$ is an abelian group. I am now reading a paper and it states that we think of an n-cochain as a set of n-simplexes. I don't understand how we can do this since the elements of $C_{n}$ are maps. Any help?

Comment: If $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ then you can identify a cochain with its support, the set of simplices where it takes value 1.

Comment: It seems that you consider simplicial homology of simplicial complexes. But $C_n(X)$ is not the free abelian group generated by the $n$-simplices of $X$. It is the  free abelian group generated by the *oriented* $n$-simplices of $X$ modulo the equivalence relation $\sigma \sim - \sigma'$, where  $\sigma, - \sigma'$ have the opposite orientation.